# Socket.io offline behaviour server-side

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have run into an unforeseen problem with my socket.io setup.

I use socket.io to live load data from my database (mongoDB, nodejs, react).

To accomplish this, I use mongoDB's changestream to detect changes and then push them to the front-end via socket.io.

Now this works perfectly as long as the user is connected. And right now, when the user reconnects, it just reloads all data. While this is fine for most users, there is a small group with very bad network connection and thus the front-end is reloading data all the time. Which causes the front-end to be unresponsive for some time.

So, I am looking for a way to only send events that occurred during the front-end being offline. While the front-end can do this quite easily: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-offline-behavior/

It doesn't seem possible to do this at the server side. Since socket.io (server side) immediately forgets sockets that have disconnected and thus cant buffer events.

So, I was wondering if there is a good way do this? Or would this need a full "wrapper" around socket.io that caches disconnected sockets?

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I find it is a really interesting and painful problem ! ^^'

If you can give more variables, it may help people to give you a better answer

For instance

- How many data are stored in database, how much a typical user will receive, and how many events are triggered on a time frame ?
- How long should an event take to be visible ? I mean, if users receive an event with a 10s,30s,... delay, is it harmfull for the service they provide.
- How your data is structured ? is it a simple json array with the same field, custom field, dynamic json object, etc..
- How your react app is structured, do you put heavy logic when your data is update, etc..

---

I think you should put more controls in your front end code and update only when new datas.

Some paths to explore

**1. Put more controls in your front end**

As you stated, for the users with bad connection, the react client seems to update his state too quickly, when they reload data after the websocket is connected, again and again. Ui may freeze in this case, yes.

For this, I think of two approaches :

- Before updating the state, check if react current state is the same as the data you receive from websocket connection. If the reconnection is quick enough and no new data arrived, it should be the same. So in this case do not update react state.
- If too many events are triggered and after each reconnection new data arrived, you can buffer the datas from the websocket and display it only once per time frame. What i mean by time frame, is you can use functions like setInterval or requestAnimationFrame to trigger react update. A pseudo react code to illustrate this.

```javascript
function App() {

  const [events, setEvents] = useState({ datas: [] });
  const bufferedEvents = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    websocket.on("connected", (newEvents) => {
      bufferedEvents.current = bufferedEvents.current.concat(newEvents);
    })

    websocket.on("data", (newEvent) => {
      bufferedEvents.current = bufferedEvents.current.concat(newEvent);
    })

    // In the setInterval function you take all the events receive at the connection + new events. to update the react state. You clean the bufferedEvents at the same time.
    const intervalId=setInterval(() => {
      const events = bufferedEvents.current;
      bufferedEvents.current = [];
      //update if new datas
      if (events.length > 0) {
        setEvents((prevState) => { return { datas: prevState.datas.concat(events) } });
      }
      // console.log(events)
    }, 1000) // trigger data update every second. You could replace this approach with a requestAnimationFrame. You can adapt the time refresh as you need.

    //Do not forget to clear the interval when the component is unmount
    return ()=>{
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }, []);

  return (

    <div>
      <span>Total events : {events.datas.length}</span>
      <br />
      {
        events.datas.map(event => {
          return <div>{event.data}</div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/) article for details on using requestAnimation frame.

---

I think that modifying the front end is needed in all case, but still alone, not really good on performance.

**2. Fetch only new data in your back end**

For this approach, it really depends how your data is structured in the database.
If the data have some timestamp in it, I can think of a naive but simple cookie with a timestamp in it.

1. When user connects the first time, this cookie is null.
2. When they fetch the data, on the websocket connection, they receive all the datas. When datas arrived, you update the cookie timestamp with the most recent date in the data.
3. Websocket is disconnected, you open a new websocket with the cookie timestamp on it. With this information you can query all the datas more recent than the timestamp on the cookie.

Like this, you don't have to download the entirity of data, but only fresh ones.

---

Other approaches may be more helpfull but without more informations on your datas and more precise requirements, it is hard to say.

If you have **a lot** of data, I will personally check some [pagination mechanism](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/simple-pagination-with-node-js-mongoose-and-express-4942af479ab2) and maybe combine some classic http request for fetching the data, and websocket, sse, or long polling for live events.

You can put a comment if needed and I will update my response !

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the interesting solutions, I think that for my use case option 2 would be best, although I would implement it a bit different since it's also possible that the user has lost access to certain documents. So, I was thinking of the following solution:

For updated documents: Save the disconnectedAt date on the front-end, on reconnect pass this date to the backend.

For deleted documents: Send a list of Id's that the front-end has saved, backend can then check if the user still has access and send a delete event if not.

Do you think this would be sufficient?

Comment: Hi, your UI seems to freeze because your websocket reconnect and update react state so much. So you will need to put some controls on your front end before updating the state. It is just a guess at this point, you will need to investigate. If it is the case, review how you update your state when websocket is connected and receive data.

Comment: For your question and use case in comment, hard to say properly without knowing more about your code, workflows, database structure, etc.. Yes you can send multiple value to your backend, when reaching the websocket endpoint, before the ws upgrade. So at first glance, I think your approach should work and you can have some difference mechanism to properly update.

Comment: Is it sufficient ? I am not sure, I am doing a lot of guesses,. You can post another question with more details and exact requirements. Or you could create a chat room and invite me in so we can dig further